# How to Cascade on Delete with PhpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I want to clear some tables in my test environment and later fill them with values from the real environment. But I don't want to clear multiple tables, there are too many.

One example:
I have a table `appointment` and a table `client`.
In the table `appointment` there's a column for the `client.id`.
When I click on `Empty the table (TRUNCATE)` in PhpMyAdmin for `appointment` all the entries in `client` stay the same.

Can I set some properties in PhpMyAdmin so that all entries in `client` related to `appointment` will be deleted too when I hit `Empty the table (TRUNCATE)` in `appointment`?

Comment: If your schema does not have FOREIGN KEY constraints specified for your tables, cascading will not work automatically.

Comment: If it will work automatically afterwards and it's possible to do it with PhpMyAdmin, then you got the right answer if you tell me how!! :)

Answer (score 5):

Before you begin, both tables must have innodb storage engine.
The answer i am providing assumes that clientid is the primary key. You cannot set appointment.clientid as primary because it is not unique. You should set client.id as primary key instead. So when you delete a clientid from clients table all appointments with that clientid will be deleted. 
Select the appointment table, click table structure and open "relation view" link . 
[Appointment table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDtMJ.png)

In the relations menu, select the clientid column and set Foreign key constraint with client.id column. Finally select CASCADE option ON DELETE.
[Relations menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI3HR.png)